# Importing Bourbon with broccoli-sass

Tags: ember.js, bourbon, broccolijs

I have installed Bourbon with Bower, but cannot get broccoli-sass to import Bourbon. Broccoli-sass is compiling my app.scss file to app.css.

I have tried

```
@import '_bourbon';
```

and

```
@import 'bourbon';
```

at the top of my app.scss file but get the error:

*Error: file to import not found or unreadable: _bourbon*

My brocfile:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var compileSass = require('broccoli-sass');

var app = new EmberApp();

var sassImportPaths = [
  'app/styles',
  'bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets',
];

var appCss = compileSass(sassImportPaths, 'app.scss', '/assets/app.css');


module.exports = app.toTree([appCss]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to import it in your Brocfile. You can simply add Bourbon as a dependency in your `app.scss`:

```
@import "bower_components/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/bourbon.scss";
```

If you look at this file you will see that it contains all the necessary imports.

Comment: This does work, I guess it's not the way I've seen it done in examples (although the examples don't seem to work for me). And it doesn't *look*  right, but if it works it works!